# Can you anti-dot? (9-22 from Marion Thorton)

Tags: energy, kinematics, vectors, collision

I'm solving a question out of the textbook and it reduces to the following.

a particle of mass 2m with velocity $v_0$ collides with a particle of mass m at rest. The collision is elastic.

So using conservation of momentum we can deduce that
$$2m\vec{v_0 }= 2m \vec{u_1} + m\vec{u_2} $$
Here $u_1$ is the final velocity in the same reference frame of the 2m particle, etc.

We also know that energy is conserved:
$$\frac{1}{2}2m\vec{v_0 }^2= \frac{1}{2}2m \vec{u_1}^2 + \frac{1}{2}m\vec{u_2}^2 $$

So we are given the system, after simplifying

$$2\vec{v_0 }= 2 \vec{u_1} + \vec{u_2} $$
$$2\vec{v_0 }^2=  2\vec{u_1}^2 + \vec{u_2}^2 $$

I would like to get the $u_1$ and $u_2$ in terms of each other so I did the following:
$$2\vec{v_0 }= 2 \vec{u_1} + \vec{u_2} $$
Dot both sides with itselves
$$4\vec{v_0 }^2= 4 \vec{u_1}^2 + \vec{u_2}^2 +4 \vec{u_1}\cdot\vec{u_2} $$

Substitute into the energy equation
$$\frac{1}{2}(4 \vec{u_1}^2 + \vec{u_2}^2 +4 \vec{u_1}\cdot\vec{u_2}) =  2\vec{u_1}^2 + \vec{u_2}^2$$

$$(2 \vec{u_1}^2 + \frac{1}{2}\vec{u_2}^2 +2 \vec{u_1}\cdot\vec{u_2}) =  2\vec{u_1}^2 + \vec{u_2}^2$$

Subtract $u_1$ squared terms

$$(\frac{1}{2}\vec{u_2}^2 +2 \vec{u_1}\cdot\vec{u_2}) = \vec{u_2}^2$$

Subtract $u_2^2$ terms and multiply by 2

$$4 \vec{u_1}\cdot\vec{u_2} = \vec{u_2}^2$$

Now here is the suspect step: can I "antidot" and do the following: if yes, why is this phyiscally correct, if not, what properties makes it incorrect:

$$4\vec{u_1} = \vec{u_2}$$

Comment: Hi @Jlee523 : Are you saying that $\vec{u}\cdot\vec{v} =0$ implies that $\vec{u}=\vec{0}$ or $\vec{v}=\vec{0}$??

Comment: Why not just use the fact that relative velocity before the collision is equal and opposite to the relative velocity after the collision?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your equation $4 {\bf u_1} .  {\bf u_2}={\bf u_2}^2$ can be written $4 u_1 u_2 cos \theta = u_2^2$ where $\theta$ is the angle between ${\bf u_1}$ and ${\bf u_2}$ . You can cancel a factor of $u_2$ and get $4u_1 cos\theta = u_2$,
but "cancelling the dot" means setting $\theta$ to zero.

If this is a 1-dimensional problem - if you have been told that the two outgoing particles head off on the same direction, which is also the direction of the initial particle, then this is fine. (Perhaps the question is asked about trucks on a railway?)

If this is a 2 (or 3 ) dimensional problem then you do not have enough information to predict the final velocities. If these are balls on a billiard table then 
the angle of scatter and the energy transfer can vary, depending on whether the
impact parameter (the initial distance between the two centres, perpendicular to the direction of motion) is large (small angle, low energy transfer scatter) or small (large angle, large energy transfer). This information is not (apparently) provided, so you cannot determine $u_1$ and/or $u_2$.

Answer (score 2):

Using your equation we get:
$$4 \vec{u_1}\cdot\vec{u_2} = \vec{u_2}^2$$
$$4 \vec{u_1}\cdot\vec{u_2} = \vec{u_2}\cdot\vec{u_2}$$
$$(4 \vec{u_1} - \vec{u_2})\cdot\vec{u_2}=0$$
From this equation you have either $(4 \vec{u_1} - \vec{u_2})=0$, $\vec{u_2}=0$, or that these vectors are orthogonal. So the "antidot" operation is not possible, unless you are certain that the vectors $(4 \vec{u_1} - \vec{u_2})$ and $\vec{u_2}$ are not perpendicular.